# is there any region tag in dreamweaver cs6 that functional alike visual studio has?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, dreamweaver, region

in visual studio we can add "REGION" so we can collapse and expand our code in category so i easy to find when our code is too many line aand we can keep it neat with that

ex :

```
#region method
code here
#endregion
```

is there some code in dreamweaver that worked like that?

***Update for @NewBie answer, dunno about the comment section can't do some line break lol**

Here is what i do

```
#region fields
here is i keep all my public stuff
#endregion

#region events
here is all of my event
#endregion

#region methods
over here is all i keep my method
#endregion
```

just try to keep my code neat, so i don't have to see what i don't need to see, but i find this way in NetBeans latest version (i never tried older one). NetBeans do almost the same way Visual Studio do, it's cool, u have to tried that hahaha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use code/tag in Dreamweaver.  Select the part of code than you want to collapse and click on minus sign in the left gutter.  Your code will be collapsed and Dreamweaver will remember this.

You can find more options in **Edit**, **Code Collapse** menu.  For example, you can collapse HTML tag and its children by selecting **Collapse Full Tag**.

Comment: still it can't give me a way to name some region, ex :
in visual studio, i usually separate my code like this :

Comment: #region methods
over here is all i keep my method
#endregion

Comment: #region fields
here is i keep all my public stuff
#endregion

#region events
here is all of my event
#endregion

#region methods
over here is all i keep my method
#endregion

just try to keep my code neat, so i don't have to see what i don't need to see, but i find this way in NetBeans latest version (i never tried older one). NetBeans do almost the same way Visual Studio do, it's cool, u have to tried that hahaha